# What content type to force download of text response?

Tags: asp.net

I need to stream a file to the Response for saving on the end user's machine.  The file is plain text, so what content type can I use to prevent the text being displayed in the browser?

Comment: Related: [Do I need Content-Type: application/octet-stream for file download?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20508788/95735)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To be on the safe side and ensure consistent behavior in all browsers, it's usually better to use both:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"My Text File.txt\"
```

Comment: You only need the content disposition, that way you can keep a relevant content type, like text/plain, or whatever.

Comment: @MattConnolly Where do you propose to *keep a relevant content type* if you are not going to use `Content-Type` header?

Comment: If I pass this as header from server side, how can front-end use it?  I can't use <a>.  Let's say if I want use a fetch call.

Answer (score 27):

In most cases, the following should work:

```
Content-type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myfile.txt"
```

There are some marginal cases of browsers that will still display it as a text file, but none of the mainstream browsers will (I'm talking about browsers embedded in some MIDs).

---

*EDIT*: When this answer was originally published, sending the Mime-Type `application/octet-stream` was the only reliable way to trigger a download in some browsers. Now in 2016, if you do not need to support an ancient browser, you can safely specify the proper mime-type.

Comment: Do you need to lie about the Content-type? Would be nicer if you could just use Content-Disposition, which /should/ work.

Comment: In my experience, application/octet-stream makes it work more reliably across all browsers.

Comment: ^ What he said. Internet Explorer 6 may still display it as text if text/plain is used.

Comment: This answer isn't particularly asp.net specific, is it?

Comment: @Shurane: No, it applies to any type of project/language sending data via the HTTP protocol. Use can use [`header()`](http://php.net/header) in PHP to send those.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: At the time of writing of this answer, `application/octet-stream` was the only way to effectively force a download under IE6. Conditions have changed since then and yes, now, you should use the proper mime-type.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it works that way.

Use a `Content-Disposition: attachment` header, but stick with the correct Content-Type.

Comment: Only send `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` when User-Agent is Internet Explorer 6...