# Unable to open a text file in notepad via Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm unable to open a text file in notepad via the Javascript function below. If you'd like to help please run this self explanatory script. Thanks.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  function RunURL(URL,Name) {
  window.open (URL,Name,
  "Width=1010,\
  Height=800,\
  Top=0,\
  Left=0,\
  Channelmode=0,\
  Titlebar=0,\
  Menubar=0,\
  Toolbar=0,\
  Directories=0,\
  Location=0,\
  Status=0,\
  Scrollbars=1,\
  Resizable=1,\
  Fullscreen=0");
  }

  </script>
```

Unfortunately I can't post the code in one piece...

```
  <html><form>

  <h2>Trying to open a text file in notepad for an Intranet app...</h2><br>

  First the easy one...<br>

  <input Type="button"; Value="Open Notepad"; OnClick="RunURL('file:///C:/Windows/system32/notepad.exe')";><br>

  <br>Now to open a text file so let's start with some common sense for the parameters as displayed in the buttons...<br>

  <input Type="button"; Value="?=C:\Test.txt"; OnClick="RunURL('file:///C:/Windows/system32/notepad.exe?=C:\Test.txt')";><br>
  <input Type="button"; Value="?=file:///C:/Test.txt"; OnClick="RunURL('file:///C:/Windows/system32/notepad.exe?=file:///C:/Test.txt')";><br>
  <input Type="button"; Value="?C:\Test.txt"; OnClick="RunURL('file:///C:/Windows/system32/notepad.exe?C:\Test.txt')";><br>

  <br>Desperation takes over!<br>

  <input Type="button"; Value="?open=file:///C:/Test.txt"; OnClick="RunURL('file:///C:/Windows/system32/notepad.exe?open=file:///C:/Test.txt')";><br>
  <input Type="button"; Value="?open=C:\Test.txt"; OnClick="RunURL('file:///C:/Windows/system32/notepad.exe?open=C:\Test.txt')";><br>
  <input Type="button"; Value="?open=C:/Test.txt"; OnClick="RunURL('file:///C:/Windows/system32/notepad.exe?open=C:/Test.txt')";><br>
  <input Type="button"; Value="?C:/Test.txt"; OnClick="RunURL('file:///C:/Windows/system32/notepad.exe?C:/Test.txt')";><br>

  <br>Could the file association alone trigger notepad to open it?<br>

  <input Type="button"; Value="file:///C:/Test.txt"; OnClick="RunURL('file:///C:/Test.txt')";><br>
  <input Type="button"; Value="C:/Test.txt"; OnClick="RunURL('C:/Test.txt')";><br>

  <br>Nope!<br>
  </form></html>
```

Maybe I should go back to flipping burgers... :(

Comment: Think of how bad this would be if it was possible? `nastysite.com?run=format c:\ `.

Comment: Even scarier when you can't open your own text files on your Intranet! :)

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to open an instance of Notepad? And what do you expect to happen after Notepad is opened?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use JavaScript to open local files like this - a security mechanism that ensures that websites around the world can't execute any program they want on your computer.

If the browser were allowed to execute `C:/Windows/system32/notepad.exe`, what would stop it from calling `format c:`?

Comment: But it's for an Intranet app... :)

Comment: @mariospolycarpou - They browser doesn't know that.

Comment: @mariospolycarpou - Not that I know.

Comment: @mariospolycarpou - You can server a `.txt` file and depending on the served headers it can either open in the browser, or the user gets asked for it to be saved/viewed.

Comment: Btw, does the format utility still exist in Win 7 and Vista? I haven't checked! :)

Comment: @mariospolycarpou - Completely off topic, but of course it does. Why wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can open a document in Notepad like this:

```
RunURL('C:/Windows/system32/notepad.exe C:\Test.txt')
```

**Note:** You will have to use Windows style directory separator — **`\`** — for first `"notepad.exe"` argument.

---

**Edit:** As *Oded* said:

> If the browser were allowed to execute
>   C:/Windows/system32/notepad.exe, what would stop it from calling
>   format c:?

You will get a "Download" of a local copy of **notepad**, and not an execution of it.

---

**Edit 2:** Also take a look at this:

> [How can I run a program or batch file on the client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877774/how-can-i-run-a-program-or-batch-file-on-the-client-side)

Comment: In JavaScript in the browser?

Comment: So is Microsoft's disk I/O via VBScript the only solution guys?

Comment: yes, and I think it will only work on the Internet Explorer browsers

Comment: Hmm... IE only is a major obstacle! :(

Comment: what are you trying to acchive excatly?