# what request headers are required to upload file in BackgroundUploader

Tags: windows-phone-8, file-io, windows-8, winjs

i am trying to upload file in Windows 8 tablet as follows

```
var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri( uriString );
var uploader = new Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.BackgroundUploader();
uploader.method = "POST";

uploader.setRequestHeader( "file", file.name );
uploader.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data" );
upload = uploader.createUpload( uri, file );
```

i
 am calling server script which is written in PHP and that is as follows

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
}
?>
```

but when i execute the code in windows 8 , its showing me following error

```
Notice: Undefined index: file in upload.php
```

this is happening because i am missing something wrong in setting up the request headers `uploader.setRequestHeader` , so can anyone tell me what request headers i should set it to make it work.

Comment: `uploader.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "application/octet-stream" );` Just a shot in the dark here. JS is not my ballgame.  [linked?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20509354/2285592)

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to fix this too, because I'm calling my php file, but I can't get the file.
Anyway, you have to put another function to make it working

```
upload .startAsync().then(
  function succes(resultat) {
    console.log('file uploaded');
  },

  function erreur(resultat) {
    console.log('there is an error');
  },

  function progression(resultat) {
    var pourcentage = Math.round(resultat.progress.bytesSent * 100 / resultat.progress.totalBytesToSend);
    console.log(pourcentage + ' %');
  }
);
```

Let me know if you find out how to make the php work !