# How do I open Mpp file directly in chrome without getting download

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I have a .mpp file in my localfolder onclick I want to open in a browser without getting direct download in chrome.

Is it possible to do directly open in chrome or IE ?

I have tried through XmlHtttp request but through this I can able to open only .txt files not an .XLS AND .mpp file.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to open in a browser without getting direct download in chrome.

You are searching for the http header [Content-Disposition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20509354/956660):

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.mpp"
```

Comment: Hi Cybril, i want to do in client side(through javascript) only how do i do that?

Comment: Mpp is a file type that is not natively supported in chrome, your options are: Convert to a supported file format or: Use an [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/project-viewer-365-free/kmpghmkgkalhonankenfklpmdgnilapp) able to read this format in chrome .