# Can we identify whether we have done cut or copy from paste event in Browsers using JS?

Tags: javascript, clipboard

If we perform cut or copy in the browser text box and perform a paste else where.
Can we detect whether the source is from cut or copy from the paste event in browsers ?

```js
document.querySelector('.box').addEventListener('paste', function(event) {
  // How can we identify wheter cut or copy is performed on text from the paste event


})
```

```css
.box {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<textarea> </textarea>

<div class='box' tabIndex=0> </div>
```

Comment: I don't think that you can.

Comment: Check the MIME type of clipboardData.  Refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790587/how-to-determine-mime-type-of-copy-pasted-image-clipboard)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270886/event-clipboarddata-setdata-in-copy-event)