# Getting Microsoft 10 Edge browser Mime Types php

Tags: php, mime-types, microsoft-edge

When checking the file mime types of files being uploaded in Microsoft 10's Edge browser, I get this Mime Type for `.doc` files:

```
application/octet-stream
```

Apparently this indicates "arbitrary binary data": [Do I need Content-Type: application/octet-stream for file download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508788/do-i-need-content-type-application-octet-stream-for-file-download)

On other browsers I get `application/msword`

Is there a new way mime types are handled for .doc files for the Edge browser, and maybe other mime types I need to be aware of?

**Update:**

I was grabbing the mime type using php's `$_FILES['uploadName']['type']`

Comment: smells like a bug - how about reporting it

Comment: You should not grab the MIME type from the data given in `$_FILE` as this is extremely flaky and up for interpretation, as you are experiencing. Instead, do a new analysis of the uploaded **temporary** file, Use `finfo()` or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that by using this instead, I get the correct mime type:

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mimeType = $finfo->file($_FILES['uploadName']['tmp_name'][$key]);
```

And as Martin mentioned in a comment above:

> You should not grab the MIME type from the data given in $_FILE as
>   this is extremely flaky and up for interpretation, as you are
>   experiencing. Instead, do a new analysis of the uploaded temporary
>   file, Use finfo() or similar.

Comment: I should have read your answer before my comment above, oh well.... Glad you found the more reliable way of doing it

Comment: Yea thanks it's a good comment and worth people seeing if they ever come here, I will add to my answer.