# Upload File with Jersey 2

Tags: java, rest, file-upload, jersey-2.0

I need to upload a binary file through a rest call using Jersey 2

I have write the following class:

```
@Path("/entry-point")
public class EntryPoint {

    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public String uploadStream( InputStream payload ) throws IOException
    {
        while(true) {
            try {
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(payload);
                System.out.println(dis.readByte());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                break;
            }
        }
        //Or you can save the inputsream to a file directly, use the code, but must remove the while() above.
        /**
         OutputStream os =new FileOutputStream("C:\recieved.jpg");
         IOUtils.copy(payload,os);
         **/
        System.out.println("Payload size="+payload.available());
        return "Payload size="+payload.available();
    }

}
```

When I try to do something like the following:

```
curl --request POST --data-binary "@file.txt" http://localhost:8080/entry-point/upload
```

I get the following response:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 415 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 415</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /entry-point/up. Reason:
<pre>    Unsupported Media Type</pre></p>
<hr /><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.6.v20151106</a><hr/>
</body>
</html>
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved removing `@Consumes` annotation.

Like this

```
public String uploadStream(InputStream payload) throws IOException {}
```

Comment: So what's the default media type if not stated?

Answer (score 1):

Server side looks OK. Adding the content mime type as stated in the error solved the issue for me:

`-H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream'`

Answer (score 0):

You should use MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA to indicate to Jersey that what you are going to receive is a file. In addition, you have to 'hint' jersey which field should be the one you want to read. A corrected version would be :

```
 @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
 public String uploadStream( @FormDataParam("file") InputStream payload ) throws IOException {
```

Note that MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM is a generic MediaType. For a more detailed explanation check : [Do I need Content-Type: application/octet-stream for file download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508788/do-i-need-content-type-application-octet-stream-for-file-download)

Comment: Did you try to add as header the multipart/form-data Content-Type such as :  `curl --request POST --data-binary "@file.txt" http://localhost:8080/entry-point/upload -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'`

Comment: Sorry for late. I was in vacation. I have try your call and now I get `Error 400 Bad Request`