# PHP - Forcing download a file not working

Tags: php

**code.php**

```
$code = $_GET["code"];
$file = 'code/'.$code.'.html';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

**Generated URL to download the file:**

```
http://www.example.com/code.php?code=yoursite.com_nbsp63ibrf
```

Well, I want to forcing download the html file, above code not working and it just preview the file at browser!

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508788/do-i-need-content-type-application-octet-stream-for-file-download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately it was a encoding issue. I changed `code.php` encoding from UTF-8 to UTF-8 Without BOM then problem solved. Thanks for all answers and helps. I forgot that PHP header only works with UTF-8 Without BOM.

Answer (score 1):

file_exists() returns false. Change your path with document root:

```
$code = $_GET["code"];
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/code/' . $code . '.html'; // set your path from document root.
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but still 'forcing download' not working, it just preview the html file at browser

Comment: The most simple way is this: var_dump($file); So you can see the path is correct. If file_exists is true, the script stops after exit. ;-)

Comment: it will return "" string(79) "/xxxxx/homepages/5/d134578306/htdocs/MySite/code/yoursite.com_nbsp63ibrf.html "" the path is correct

Comment: Okay, then: var_dump(file_exists($file)); If it returns true, it's good

Comment: yep, it return: bool(true)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not possible.
The browser can always decide on its own, if the file should be downloaded or not.

The furthest you can go is sending the content-disposition header.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the content type to match the file type and setting the transfer encoding to binary:

```
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Type: text/html');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$code = $_GET["code"];
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/code/' . $code . '.html'; // set your path from document root.
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header("Content-Type: text/html");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");   
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");   
    header("Content-Type: application/download");     
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but nothing changed.. still file won't download

Comment: check the file exits in your directory.

Comment: file exits, because it preview the file in browser!

Comment: i checked with two browser, chrome, firefox, both not working and still preview the file instead of download