# Setting HTTP response headers with Kemal

Tags: http, crystal-lang, kemal

I want implement [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11894771/5843840) in Kemal.

My current setup has a pdf file in `app/public/map.pdf`, and the following code in my main crystal file:

```
require "kemal"

#...

get "/map.pdf" do |env|
    env.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/pdf"
    env.response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = %(inline;filename="myfile.pdf")
end

Kemal.run
```

When I test my code by opening `localhost:3000/map.pdf` in a browser (firefox), it prompts to download the file (while I want it to attempt to display it). And `curl -I` results in the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Kemal
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
ETag: W/"1494983019"
Content-Length: 1170498
```

Where I would hope to see `Content-Type: application/pdf`.

Comment: Hi! 
Firstly, I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508788/do-i-need-content-type-application-octet-stream-for-file-download
could be helpful. Secondly, what is your actual question?

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked. Are you sure you are stopping the server and compiling again the application? Making changes without recompiling will have no effect.

Answer (score 3):

Kemal author here,

If the headers are ok you should be good to go with `send_file`. However be sure that the route name and file are not the same. In this case the route is `/pdf`

```
get "/pdf" do |env|
  env.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/pdf"
  env.response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = %(inline;filename="map.pdf")
  send_file env, "./public/map.pdf"
end
```

Comment: With those changes, it still prompts to download, and not content-type is `Content-Type: text/html`.

Answer (score -2):

> Where I would hope to see Content-Type: application/pdf.

The point is that `Content-Disposition` doesn't exist as a header.
Maybe you don't send any headers at all for some reason.

For example in PHP, if your script outputs a single byte before it sends the headers then no headers will be sent; only the headers before the first output.
If you set a http header after some data is sent then the header will be ignored.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say in your second paragraph.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how does it answer this question? Because I'm sorry, but I think it does not, at all.