# Prevent browsers from opening json files and instead download when sent from flask app

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, web-applications

I have a JSON file in the flask app that i send via either send_from_directory() or via send_file() i have tried both. This triggers on button click but the browser opens the file directly instead of getting a download dialog box. I researched a bit and found out Firefox and Chrome have an inbuilt option to do this, however i want it to always download instead of opening no matter the setting in the browser.

**Flask Code**

```
def download_file():
    filename = "requiredFields.json"

    return send_from_directory(app.config['MAIN_FOLDER'],filename,as_attachment=True)
```

**HTML That calls it**

```
<a href="{{url_for('download_file',filename = file)}}"class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Download</a>
```

Comment: probably if you send it with `content-type`/`mime-type` like for `zip` or `exe` file then browser as default should download it.

Comment: [Do I need Content-Type: application/octet-stream for file download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508788/do-i-need-content-type-application-octet-stream-for-file-download)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `mimetype` to `'application/octet-stream'` then browser should save it.

```
send_file(..., mimetype='application/octet-stream')

send_from_directory(..., mimetype='application/octet-stream')
```

Doc: [send_file](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_file)

See also: [Do I need Content-Type: application/octet-stream for file download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508788/do-i-need-content-type-application-octet-stream-for-file-download)

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working example - you have to only set correct filenames in `index()`

It doesn't matter if you have file `.json`, `.txt`, image, `.pdf` or other. It works for all types of files.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, send_from_directory

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MAIN_FOLDER'] = '.'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    all_filenames = [
        'requiredFields.json',
        'input.txt',
        'image.jpg',
        'document.pdf',
    ]
    
    return render_template_string('''
{% for file in all_files %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('download_file', filename=file) }}">Download {{file}}</a><br/>
{% endfor %}''', all_files=all_filenames)

#@app.route('/download_file/<filename>')
@app.route('/download_file/<path:filename>')
def download_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['MAIN_FOLDER'], filename, as_attachment=True, attachment_filename=filename, mimetype='application/octet-stream')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app.run() #debug=True
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the response, but that still didn't work:(. Now i have two routes doing the same type of thing one is serving a JSON and one is serving a txt. Now i originally asked the question for the JSON one but that started working right as soon as i removed the filename attribute from the  <a> tag, now I'm having a problem with the txt one(Code is same) where i cannot remove that attribute and mimetype isn't fixing it:(.

Comment: for flask and browser there is no difference if you send JSON or txt - both are only bytes - and in both you can use the same code with the same `mimetype='application/octet-stream'` to force browser to download it. As for parameter `filename = file` in `url_for()` - it needs `filename` in route `@app.route('/some_page/<filename>')` and in function `def download_file(filename):`

Comment: So your answer was actually perfect, i do have all of those parameters in the code just didn't include them here. Interestingly running the code the second time worked like a charm for some reason, didn't change a thing xD