# Decode weirdly formatted requests response data in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, character-encoding

I'm parsing a website using their XHR calls, but I've noticed I have some trouble understanding what it is returning to me. My code so you can replicate

```
url = "https://api.aiscore.com/v1/web/api/matches?lang=4&sport_id=2&date=20201112&tz=01:00"
headers={'authority': 'api.aiscore.com',
 'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="86", ""Not\\A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="86"',
 'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
 'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36',
 'origin': 'https://www.aiscore.com',
 'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
 'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
 'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
 'referer': 'https://www.aiscore.com/',
 'accept-language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8'}

response=requests.get(url=url,headers=headers)

>>response.text
'zø÷\x01\n¬\x01\n\x0fmo07dzsdgcxknxy\x10\x02"6\x08\x1c\x12\x08Lituania*(d9051e0b77f8bb5521389618e70e2ada.png!w80*\x17Lietuvos krepsinio lygaB%990525c8080452649a7b68501bf53f57.jpegPàÑ\x04º\x01\x17lietuvos-krepsinio-lygaØ\x01\x04\nn\n\x0f4ndqmrsxyja5kve\x10\x02"5\x08;\x12\x07Uruguay*(75497a22409db78dcc52c291e078bc10.png!w80*\x0eUruguay Leagueº\x01\x0euruguay-leagueØ\x01\x04\n°\x01\n\x0fw34kgpsnpf1ko92\x10\x02"7\x084\x12\tArgentina*(3536be57ce0713954e454ae6c53ec023.png!w80*\x1bLiga Nacional de BosquetbolB$1dae06c27aea581100fa54e7c50d892a.gifº\x01\x1bliga-nacional-de-bosquetbolØ\x01\x04\nn\n\x0f8vmqy6sjvlbek9r\x10\x02"7\x08>\x12\tVenezuela*(e95294b730f61c8175550ec244bfcb50.png!w80*\rVenezuela LPBº\x01\rvenezuela-lpbØ\x01\x04\nm\n\x0f9oj7x6srxzfe7g3\x10\x02"6\x08<\x12\x08Colombia*(ef3388cc5659bccb742fb8af762f1bfd.png!w80*\rColombia Ligaº\x01\rcolombia-ligaØ\x01\x04\nf\n\x0f2jr7o9s29gh170e\x10\x02"3\x08�N\x12\rOtros paÃ\xadses*\x1faiscore_default_country.png!w80*\x0bVietnam VBAº\x01\x0bvietnam-vbaØ\x01\x04\nZ\n\x0f9oj7x6s5gse7g3y\x10\x02"\x1b\x08…\x01\x12\x06Kosovo*\x0ekosovo.png!w80*\x11Kosovo Division Iº\x01\x11kosovo-division-iØ\x01\x04\nž\x01\n\x0fzjek3ps65hvqo29\x10\x02"5\x08 \x12\x07Croacia*(560d4c6ff431c86546f3fcec72c748c7.png!w80*\x13Croatian A-1 LeagueB$f0e275b18af005a1e8c931582f7bb3bd.gifº\x01\x13croatian-a-1-leagueØ\x01\x04\ni\n\x0fw34kgpso8b1ko92\x10\x02"6\x08\x17\x12\x08RumanÃ\xada*(0c7d5ae44b2a0be9ebd7d6b9f7d60f20.png!w80*\x0bRomania CUPº\x01\x0bromania-cupØ\x01\x04\n»\x01\n\x0f2ezk90s60c2kn51\x10\x02",\x08‘N\x12\rInternacional*\x181552909490097161.png!w80*&Balkan International Basketball LeagueB$7e2cccee37653bb9ffb7a37152dd1091.jpgº\x01&balkan-international-basketball-leagueØ\x01\x04\n®\x01\n\x0f9oj7x6srpae7g3y\x10\x02"7\x08\r\x12\tDinamarca*(424214945ba5615eca039bfe5d731c09.png!w80*\x18Danish Basketball LeagueB$533c6b6c2fc9e2fb51cb315dc279eaa8.pngPð¢\x04º\x01\x18danish-basketball-leagueØ\x01\x04\nº\x01\n\x0f0xo17p8sxu3kjw5\x10\x02"3\x08E\x12\x05China*(38aed2a85bd723ca6749216d37b9a989.png!w80*!National Basketball League(China)B$89c4ae7c1e21e4219149a70f6faab848.jpgPØ\xad\x03º\x01\x1fnational-basketball-leaguechinaØ\x01\x04\n‰\x01\n\x0fn527rjspdyb1kev\x10\x02"6\x08\x1f\x12\x08TurquÃ\xada*(221cdfb73049678e244380b45872cbb2.png!w80*\x1bTurkey Federation Cup Womenº\x01\x1bturkey-federation-cup-womenØ\x01\x04\n„\x01\n\x0fr8lk2yso9t0736d\x10\x02"5\x08\x14\x12\x07Ucrania*(f01fc92b23faa973f3492a23d5a705c5.png!w80*\x04UBSLB$115e3dd59ec30a24a18a22e4a285ce6f.jpgPð¢\x04º\x01\x04ubslØ\x01\x04\n�\x01\n\x0fyzrknxslwujqle4\x10\x02"4\x08#\x12\x06Chipre*(ea2ba3f8011e19e3101ce65fdcefbcc4.png!w80*\x13Apollon Limassol BCB$ef154681b0256ec0693beb6c7116a71d.pngº\x01\x13apollon-limassol-bcØ\x01\x04\n²\x01\n\x0fyw6975lsjh2k23e\x10\x02";\x08G\x12\rCorea del Sur*(e0152977a41868ebc941f4e85e90a31b.png!w80*\x18Korean Basketball LeagueB$4c0624a972fbbb2390e46fac63e09430.pngP�Å\x03º\x01\x18korean-basketball-leagueØ\x01\x04\nÆ\x01\n\x0f5xvkjvs93frk938\x10\x02"5\x08\x0e\x12\x07Austria*(9891739094756d2605946c867b32ad28.png!w80*%Osterreichische Basketball BundesligaB$6e340c3414dcc2a34ea78667a5ca686f.jpgPð¢\x04º\x01%osterreichische-basketball-bundesligaØ\x01\x04\n¥\x01\n\x0f5xvkjvs3gtrk938\x10\x02"6\x08\x04\x12\x08Alemania*(d8b00929dec65d422303256336ada04f.png!w80*\x16Germany Basketball CupB$eb44b5509fa3ae45fd315b1858a9f811.jpgº\x01\x16germany-basketball-cupØ\x01\x04\n”\x01\n\x0f59gkl6symwt3kxd\x10\x02"%\x08’N\x12\x06Europa*\x181552909490161265.png!w80*\x16Adriatic Basketball D2B$f4c95209caa7f3bcb3c95011d2236895.pngº\x01\x16adriatic-basketball-d2Ø\x01\x04\nÓ\x01\n\x0fw6975ls3js2k23e\x10\x02"7\x08H\x12\tAustralia*(4442e4af0916f53a07fb8ca9a49b98ed.png!w80*/Womenâ€™s National Basketball League(Australia)B$13b83bf4ccd68cb087b6a0527dc1f481.pngº\x01*womens-national-basketball-leagueaustraliaØ\x01\x04\n\x7f\n\x0fmo07dzsonaxknxy\x10\x02"%\x08’N\x12\x06Europa*\x181552909490161265.png!w80*\nEuroleagueB$c14acac79745b832757d690233ddade0.jpg°\x01\x01º\x01\neuroleagueØ\x01\x04\nÃ\x01\n\x0fjmo07dzsgtxknxy\x10\x02"5\x08\x03\x12\x07EspaÃ±a*(907eba32d950bfab68227fd7ea22999b.png!w80*"Asociacion de Clubes de BaloncestoB$d0468eba49d311f847c7f592a647abc4.pngP°á\x04°\x01\x01º\x01"asociacion-de-clubes-de-baloncestoØ\x01\x04\n�\x01\n\x0f59gkl6s6pb3kxdv\x10\x02",\x08‘N\x12\rInternacional*\x181552909490097161.png!w80*\x0fClub FriendshipB$255ca39a3d57a8ba68c42e11f9212862.pngº\x01\x0fclub-friendshipØ\x01\x04\n\x7f\n\x0f1edq0esmg2hykxg\x10\x02"(\x08“N\x12\tAmÃ©ricas*\x181552909490206875.png!w80*\x1dPuerto Rico Superior Nacionalº\x01\x1dpuerto-rico-superior-nacionalØ\x01\x04\n¹\x01\n\x0fr1edq0es5uykxgo\x10\x02"3\x08E\x12\x05China*(38aed2a85bd723ca6749216d37b9a989.png!w80*\x1eChinese Basketball AssociationB$4bcdfa94d226fd5d7c740b463c182aa0.jpgPøÌ\x03¨\x01\x01º\x01\x1echinese-basketball-associationØ\x01\x04\n¢\x01\n\x0f0m2q19s2xhpk6xw\x10\x02"4\x085\x12\x06Brasil*(42537f0fb56e31e20ab9c2305752087d.png!w80*\x14Novo Basquete BrasilB$d5e2224278126aeca3d057e45b685838.jpg°\x01\x01º\x01\x14novo-basquete-brasilØ\x01\x04\n~\n\x0fyzrknxs43ujqle4\x10\x02"3\x08\x12\x12\x05Rusia*(5feb168ca8fb495dcc89b1208cdeb919.png!w80*\x17VTB United Youth Leagueº\x01\x17vtb-united-youth-leagueØ\x01\x04\nÀ\x01\n\x0fw34kgpsdwi1ko92\x10\x02"%\x08’N\x12\x06Europa*\x181552909490161265.png!w80*-European Basketball Championship Qualifier(W)B$6c4e1a58ab3c7d46f07f896acbda1bbe.jpgº\x01+european-basketball-championship-qualifierwØ\x01\x04\n�\x01\n\x0fyzrknxs9whjqle4\x10\x02"4\x08F\x12\x06JapÃ³n*(53a577bb3bc587b0c28ab808390f1c9b.png!w80*\tB2 LeagueB$692b6587fa9458aebb563b2e1c8c08fb.pngPØ\xad\x03º\x01\tb2-leagueØ\x01\x04\n·\x01\n\x0fw2j374wsou4ko6d\x10\x02"4\x08%\x12\x06Israel*(5a548c2f5875f10bf5614b7c258876cf.png!w80*\x1eIsrael Basketball Super LeagueB$3d858fe19e03080fe8d986250b8811f9.pngPàÑ\x04º\x01\x1eisrael-basketball-super-leagueØ\x01\x04\x12Ì\x01\n\x0fvmqy6sw50g0sgk9\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0fw34kgpsnpf1ko92*\x002\x11\n\x0feg676jsjyrtpkry:\x11\n\x0f5wv784slrlhnqrjB\x08\x10\x01\x18¥º²ý\x05b\x05,,4\x16\x00j\x05D60(\x00xˆ„²ý\x05€\x01\n¨\x01D°\x01\x0fÀ\x01\x03Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01K:I\n\x16\n\x031.1\n\x05-24.5\n\x050.666\n\x011\n\x15\n\x0418.0\n\x030.0\n\x051.004\n\x010\n\x16\n\x050.869\n\x05188.5\n\x030.8\n\x010\n\x00\x12Ë\x01\n\x0fedq0esoz0zdsekx\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0f9oj7x6srxzfe7g3*\x002\x11\n\x0fg676jsdrmdcpkry:\x11\n\x0fvmqy6sj281i4k9rB\x08\x10\x01\x18‹Á²ý\x05b\x05&*$0\x00j\x05\x1c((6\x00x�’²ý\x05€\x01\n¨\x01@°\x01\x12À\x01\x03Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01J:H\n\x15\n\x040.74\n\x031.5\n\x050.952\n\x011\n\x13\n\x031.4\n\x030.0\n\x042.75\n\x011\n\x18\n\x050.769\n\x05158.5\n\x050.909\n\x010\n\x00\x12Ç\x01\n\x0fjr7o9s14dewhg70\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0f1edq0esmg2hykxg*\x002\x11\n\x0fezk90snezniwkn5:\x11\n\x0fvrqw9solz5id7n2B\x02\x10\x01b\x05D(&,\x00j\x05"\x1e\x1e:\x00x�’²ý\x05€\x01\n¨\x01@°\x01\x06À\x01\x03Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01L:J\n\x15\n\x050.869\n\x0419.5\n\x030.8\n\x011\n\x15\n\x051.005\n\x030.0\n\x0417.0\n\x010\n\x18\n\x050.833\n\x05160.5\n\x050.833\n\x010\n\x00\x12Î\x01\n\x0fjek3psgr01pb9qo\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0f0xo17p8sxu3kjw5*\x002\x11\n\x0fzjek3pszw9tdqo2:\x11\n\x0f8lk2ysoge3c3736B\x08\x10\x01\x18î½³ý\x05b\x05(\x128&\x00j\x05B<2.\x00xØ�³ý\x05€\x01\n¨\x01@°\x01%À\x01\x03Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01M:I\n\x16\n\x031.3\n\x05-35.5\n\x050.588\n\x011\n\x13\n\x0417.0\n\x030.0\n\x031.0\n\x010\n\x18\n\x050.769\n\x05187.5\n\x050.909\n\x010\n\x00H\x01\x12Ç\x01\n\x0fndkzysj0o50bx73\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0fyzrknxs43ujqle4*\x002\x11\n\x0fo17p8s00leb2kjw:\x11\n\x0f8vrqw9sx4osd7n2B\x02\x10\x01b\x05$\x1c00\x00j\x05(\x14$\x18\x00xðº³ý\x05€\x01\n¨\x01@°\x01FÀ\x01\x03Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01L:J\n\x17\n\x050.833\n\x0420.5\n\x050.833\n\x011\n\x15\n\x051.004\n\x030.0\n\x0418.0\n\x010\n\x16\n\x040.83\n\x05147.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x00\x12ý\x01\n\x0f9gkl6srd0jdamkx\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0fw6975ls3js2k23e*\x002\x11\n\x0f2j374wsjzrarko6:\x11\n\x0f0m2q19s3votmk6xB\x0c\x08\x01\x10\x01\x18º„´ý\x05 qb\x05"4* \x00j\x05\x1e "\x1e\x00x€×³ý\x05€\x01\x08¨\x01Ä\x01°\x01Ÿ,À\x01\x02Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01v:G\n\x15\n\x050.952\n\x0417.5\n\x030.8\n\x010\n\x15\n\x051.005\n\x030.0\n\x0421.0\n\x011\n\x15\n\x040.85\n\x05150.5\n\x030.9\n\x010\n\x00B+\x12)\n\'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x13\x15\x16\x19\x1d\x1e #%+.0126y…\x01±\x01Ü\x01\x12x\n\x0fxvkjvsnyjdpt8k9\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0f0xo17p8sxu3kjw5*\x002\x11\n\x0fndkzyszv4gie73z:\x11\n\x0fr8lk2ys258b3736B\x02\x10\x01b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00xˆå³ý\x05€\x01\x0f°\x01\x04À\x01\x08Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01\x00\x12ý\x01\n\x0fo07dzsvp9g8fmkn\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0f0xo17p8sxu3kjw5*\x002\x11\n\x0fr8lk2ys24dt3736:\x11\n\x0f0ndkzyspp3be73zB\x0b\x10\x01\x18¹„´ý\x05 ä\x02b\x05$*\x14\x00\x00j\x05&(\x18\x00\x00xˆå³ý\x05€\x01\x06¨\x01À\x01°\x01¥\x1cÀ\x01\x02Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01w:F\n\x14\n\x050.869\n\x036.5\n\x030.8\n\x010\n\x14\n\x051.285\n\x030.0\n\x033.5\n\x010\n\x16\n\x050.869\n\x05173.5\n\x030.8\n\x010\n\x00B+\x12)\n\'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x13\x15\x16\x19\x1d\x1e #%+.0126y…\x01±\x01Ü\x01H\x01\x12ñ\x01\n\x0fo07dzsvp8lzumkn\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0fyw6975lsjh2k23e*\x002\x11\n\x0f1edq0es14vs4kxg:\x11\n\x0fw6975lspvoank23B\x00b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00x\xa0�´ý\x05€\x01\x01¨\x01Ä\x01°\x01·\x03À\x01\x01Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01v:G\n\x15\n\x040.91\n\x04-3.5\n\x040.91\n\x010\n\x14\n\x042.55\n\x030.0\n\x041.57\n\x010\n\x16\n\x040.91\n\x05166.5\n\x040.91\n\x010\n\x00B+\x12)\n\'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x13\x15\x16\x19\x1d\x1e #%+.0126y…\x01±\x01Ü\x01\x12Â\x01\n\x0f527rjslze4ra4ke\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0fw6975ls3js2k23e*\x002\x11\n\x0f59gkl6s2evt1kxd:\x11\n\x0f9gkl6syo1nf1kxdB\x00b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00x\xa0�´ý\x05€\x01\x01¨\x01@°\x01mÀ\x01\x01Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01I:G\n\x15\n\x040.95\n\x05-16.5\n\x030.8\n\x010\n\x14\n\x0410.0\n\x030.0\n\x041.03\n\x010\n\x16\n\x040.87\n\x05152.5\n\x040.87\n\x010\n\x00\x12Â\x01\n\x0fedq0esozpglhekx\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0fyzrknxs9whjqle4*\x002\x11\n\x0f63kvlsm4l9sp7ez:\x11\n\x0f0ndkzyswrofe73zB\x00b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00x\xa0�´ý\x05€\x01\x01¨\x01@°\x01fÀ\x01\x01Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01I:G\n\x16\n\x040.83\n\x05-14.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x13\n\x037.5\n\x030.0\n\x041.07\n\x010\n\x16\n\x040.83\n\x05155.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x00\x12Â\x01\n\x0fedq0esoz063sekx\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0fn527rjspdyb1kev*\x002\x11\n\x0f63kvlsjoz0bp7ez:\x11\n\x0fvmqy6sjn90b4k9rB\x00b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00x\xa0�´ý\x05€\x01\x01¨\x01@°\x01\x1eÀ\x01\x01Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01I:G\n\x15\n\x040.83\n\x0412.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x14\n\x041.11\n\x030.0\n\x045.75\n\x010\n\x16\n\x040.83\n\x05140.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x00\x12Á\x01\n\x0f527rjslzyz3i4ke\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0f59gkl6s6pb3kxdv*\x002\x11\n\x0fwv784spvnwhnqrj:\x11\n\x0fndqmrszd24tgkveB\x00b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00x°«´ý\x05€\x01\x01¨\x01@°\x01\'À\x01\x01Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01H:F\n\x15\n\x040.83\n\x0414.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x13\n\x041.07\n\x030.0\n\x037.5\n\x010\n\x16\n\x040.83\n\x05143.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x00\x12x\n\x0f9gkl6srdogehmkx\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0fyzrknxs43ujqle4*\x002\x11\n\x0foj7x6sw1erir7g3:\x11\n\x0fzjek3ps2vlsdqo2B\x02\x10\x01b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00x°«´ý\x05€\x01\x01°\x01\x12À\x01\x01Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01\x00\x12Ü\x01\n\x0fl6kers6ndgnsvq5\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0f0xo17p8sxu3kjw5*\x002\x11\n\x0fr8lk2ys2lga3736:\x11\n\x0fg63kvlsyrwup7ezB\x00b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00x¸¹´ý\x05€\x01\x01¨\x01À\x01°\x01.À\x01\x01Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01b:3\n\x15\n\x040.83\n\x0444.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x00\n\x16\n\x040.83\n\x05203.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x00B+\x12)\n\'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x13\x15\x16\x19\x1d\x1e #%+.0126y…\x01±\x01Ü\x01\x12©\x01\n\x0fm2q19swxl9laek6\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0f0xo17p8sxu3kjw5*\x002\x11\n\x0fxo17p8s26xt2kjw:\x11\n\x0f9oj7x6s41pcr7g3B\x02\x10\x01b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00x¸¹´ý\x05€\x01\x01¨\x01€\x01°\x01 À\x01\x01Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01-B+\x12)\n\'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x13\x15\x16\x19\x1d\x1e #%+.0126y…\x01±\x01Ü\x01\x12ó\x01\n\x0fjr7o9s1806lfg70\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0fr1edq0es5uykxgo*\x030Ÿ\x082\x11\n\x0fxo17p8sd42s2kjw:\x11\n\x0f0ndkzys0dzse73zB\x00b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00xä»´ý\x05€\x01\x01¨\x01Ä\x01°\x01ƒ\x02À\x01\x01Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01u:E\n\x14\n\x040.87\n\x033.5\n\x040.87\n\x010\n\x13\n\x041.55\n\x030.0\n\x032.5\n\x010\n\x16\n\x040.91\n\x05193.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x00B,\x12*\n(E\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x13\x15\x16\x19\x1d\x1e #%+.0126y…\x01±\x01Ü\x01\x12°\x01\n\x0foj7x6s0ve85c47g\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0fw34kgpsdwi1ko92*\x002\x11\n\x0fn527rjszgmi8kev:\x11\n\x0fn527rjszlgc8kevB\x02\x10\x01b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00xÀÇ´ý\x05€\x01\x01¨\x01@°\x01\x0fÀ\x01\x01Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x015:3\n\x15\n\x040.83\n\x0417.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x00\n\x16\n\x040.83\n\x05127.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x00\x12ó\x01\n\x0fo17p8s9mx00bykj\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0fr1edq0es5uykxgo*\x030Ÿ\x082\x11\n\x0fw6975ls4x8ink23:\x11\n\x0f5wv784sryjtnqrjB\x00b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00xÀÇ´ý\x05€\x01\x01¨\x01Ä\x01°\x01„\x01À\x01\x01Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01u:E\n\x14\n\x040.91\n\x031.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x13\n\x031.8\n\x030.0\n\x041.95\n\x010\n\x16\n\x040.87\n\x05210.5\n\x040.87\n\x010\n\x00B,\x12*\n(E\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x13\x15\x16\x19\x1d\x1e #%+.0126y…\x01±\x01Ü\x01\x12{\n\x0f527rjslzedea4ke\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0f2jr7o9s29gh170e*\x002\x11\n\x0f6975ls30n2unk23:\x11\n\x0fezk90sdgj5fwkn5B\x02\x10\x01b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00xÀÇ´ý\x05€\x01\x01¨\x01@°\x01\x14À\x01\x01Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01\x00\x12x\n\x0f6975lsz45n6hgk2\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0f59gkl6symwt3kxd*\x002\x11\n\x0fvmqy6sj5ows4k9r:\x11\n\x0fzjek3psrn9hdqo2B\x02\x10\x01b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00xÀÇ´ý\x05€\x01\x01°\x01\nÀ\x01\x01Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01\x00\x12À\x01\n\x0f34kgpse6p9rieko\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0fn527rjspdyb1kev*\x002\x11\n\x0fndkzys8o5wue73z:\x11\n\x0fjek3psjdx3tdqo2B\x00b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00xÄÎ´ý\x05€\x01\x01¨\x01@°\x01\x0eÀ\x01\x01Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01G:E\n\x15\n\x040.77\n\x0412.5\n\x040.91\n\x010\n\x12\n\x031.1\n\x030.0\n\x036.5\n\x010\n\x16\n\x040.83\n\x05152.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x00\x12Â\x01\n\x0fedq0esoz5x2hekx\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0fw34kgpsnpf1ko92*\x002\x11\n\x0fw6975lsmpwtnk23:\x11\n\x0f527rjsel0li8kevB\x02\x10\x01b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00xàÿ´ý\x05€\x01\x01¨\x01@°\x01\x0eÀ\x01\x01Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01G:E\n\x14\n\x040.83\n\x035.0\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x13\n\x041.45\n\x030.0\n\x032.6\n\x010\n\x16\n\x040.83\n\x05155.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x00\x12¯\x01\n\x0fm2q19sw611liek6\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0fw34kgpsdwi1ko92*\x002\x11\n\x0f5wv784sr80bnqrj:\x11\n\x0fndqmrszxmgtgkveB\x02\x10\x01b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00xè�µý\x05€\x01\x01¨\x01@°\x01\nÀ\x01\x01Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x014:2\n\x14\n\x040.87\n\x0445.5\n\x030.8\n\x010\n\x00\n\x16\n\x040.83\n\x05142.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x00\x12Á\x01\n\x0fwv784smr6o4coqr\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0fn527rjspdyb1kev*\x002\x11\n\x0fndkzys8j55se73z:\x11\n\x0fjr7o9sl1e0i370eB\x00b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00xè�µý\x05€\x01\x01¨\x01@°\x01\x01¨\x01@°\x01\x0fÀ\x01\x01Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01J:H\n\x16\n\x040.83\n\x05-14.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x14\n\x047.75\n\x030.0\n\x041.07\n\x010\n\x16\n\x040.83\n\x05160.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x00\x12Ã\x01\n\x0fndkzysj085rux73\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0fw34kgpsnpf1ko92*\x002\x11\n\x0fxo17p8sgvdb2kjw:\x11\n\x0fyzrknxs60phnqleB\x02\x10\x01b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00x�Ôµý\x05€\x01\x01¨\x01@°\x01\rÀ\x01\x01Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01H:F\n\x15\n\x040.83\n\x04-5.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x13\n\x032.7\n\x030.0\n\x041.41\n\x010\n\x16\n\x040.83\n\x05156.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x00\x12{\n\x0fm2q19sw3g94cek6\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0fr8lk2yso9t0736d*\x002\x11\n\x0f2ezk90s1zwbwkn5:\x11\n\x0f4ndqmrsvrrbgkveB\x02\x10\x01b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00x�Ôµý\x05€\x01\x01¨\x01@°\x01\tÀ\x01\x01Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01\x00\x12Á\x01\n\x0fndqmrs8vogjsrkv\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0fw2j374wsou4ko6d*\x002\x11\n\x0fmo07dzsplnt9knx:\x11\n\x0f2ezk90s80mswkn5B\x00b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00x�Ôµý\x05€\x01\x01¨\x01@°\x01\x12À\x01\x01Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01H:F\n\x15\n\x040.83\n\x04-3.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x13\n\x032.3\n\x030.0\n\x041.55\n\x010\n\x16\n\x040.83\n\x05161.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x00\x12Â\x01\n\x0fg676jsr8wlrsokr\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0fyzrknxslwujqle4*\x002\x11\n\x0feg676js8mphpkry:\x11\n\x0fo17p8s0yzja2kjwB\x00b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00x�Ôµý\x05€\x01\x01¨\x01@°\x01\nÀ\x01\x01Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01I:G\n\x15\n\x040.83\n\x0412.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x14\n\x041.11\n\x030.0\n\x045.75\n\x010\n\x16\n\x040.83\n\x05147.5\n\x040.83\n\x010\n\x00\x12{\n\x0foj7x6s0l6z2i47g\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0fyzrknxslwujqle4*\x002\x11\n\x0fvmqy6sjrrxc4k9r:\x11\n\x0fw6975ls92esnk23B\x02\x10\x01b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00x�Ôµý\x05€\x01\x01¨\x01@°\x01\nÀ\x01\x01Ê\x01\x00Ò\x01\x00ò\x01\x00\x12À\x01\n\x0fvrqw9s3jnzra47n\x10\x02"\x11\n\x0fw2j374wsou4ko6d*\x002\x11\n\x0f2j374wsg6gbrko6:\x11\n\x0fw34kgpsjddb8ko9B\x00b\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x05\x00\x00\x00(bf97e6db8ebd32e6e2d72d534aae307e.jpg!w80š\x01\rwuhan-dangdai\x1a`\n\x0f1edq0eszz0f4kxg\x10\x022\x0fAlbania Woman\'s:(828790716b6f4f33b06cd3a9e3c17374.jpg!w80š\x01\x0falbania-woman\'s\x1aD\n\x0fjek3psjdx3tdqo2\x10\x022\x16Sakarya Yukselis Womenš\x01\x16sakarya-yukselis-women\x1an\n\x0foj7x6sr6l2cr7g3\x10\x022\x16Edremit Belediye Women:(f777a5ea9b704e38a33945809ae34b53.png!w80š\x01\x16edremit-belediye-women\x1a^\n\x0f8vrqw9s5p3ad7n2\x10\x022\x0eUCAM Murcia CB:(e3a3ec04a37490b55dfea4d2c2157e0a.png!w80š\x01\x0eucam-murcia-cb'
```

I've tried `response.encoding`. I've tried `json.loads(response.text)`
I know this is organized roughly with the competitions on top as index, all the matched in the middle, and another index with the team's names at the bottom, but in order to actually parse it I would like something cleaner to work with.

If it is of any use, the response.headers is

```
{'Date': 'Thu, 12 Nov 2020 09:36:59 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream', 'Content-Length': '31740', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Set-Cookie': '__cfduid=d7cae3684159a856129fed3ae7f419c231605173818; expires=Sat, 12-Dec-20 09:36:58 GMT; path=/; domain=.aiscore.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure, aiclient=7dn5ocn5lq50ejo; Path=/; Domain=.aiscore.com; Max-Age=5184000', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://www.aiscore.com', 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true', 'cache-control': 'no-transform', 'CF-Cache-Status': 'DYNAMIC', 'cf-request-id': '065d69cdda0000111dpo898000000001', 'Expect-CT': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"', 'Server': 'cloudflare', 'CF-RAY': '5f0f458fred9111d-MAD'}
```

Answer (score 0):

this header `application/octet-stream` means that this is a binary file
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508788/do-i-need-content-type-application-octet-stream-for-file-download]

how ever this is not, so something is not right with this response

pls tell me if i helped :)