# Enable "Save As" option while downloading a file for the all browser

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, http-headers

I have requirement in which I need to enable save as option if the user downloads the file from the my web application.Is there any way by which i can do it through java script or setting some attribute in th response header.(This should override the browser setting which user has done for by setting the download option in settings)

Note: I cannot handle or create file in my web application (client side)space as files are large which crashes the application  so I am using content-disposition and letting the browser to handle the download

Comment: "Content-Type" = "application/octet-stream" response header => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508788/do-i-need-content-type-application-octet-stream-for-file-download

Answer (score -1):

Not at the moment due to user experience and security concerns (users have to do it manually).

But the upcoming [FileSystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem) allows for it but is not fully implemented yet.