# What's the use of Content-Type header when the response is an attachment?

Tags: html, http-headers

If the response header contains `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=image.gif`, then the data will automatically be saved by the browser. Does passing `Content-Type` header make sense in such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does make sense if you know the what the appropriate `Content-Type` header is, but **NO** it is not explicitly required.

> **[RFC6266](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6266#appendix-A) Use of the Content-Disposition Header Field in HTTP**
> According to the original [RFC 2616](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-19.5.1), the disposition type "attachment" only applies to content of type `"application/octet-stream"`. But this restriction has been removed, because recipients in practice do not always check the content type, and it also discourages properly declaring the media type.
>
> So traditionally, we used to have to always specify `Content-Type:application/octet-stream` to force a download, over time clients evolved and started ignoring it altogether if there was a disposition header header.

`Content-Type` tells the browser how to interpret the response, but `Content-Disposition: attachment` tells the browser to treat the response as a file, rather than trying to render it.

But not *ALL* clients are web browsers, and not all web browsers are equal. By providing the `Content-Type` as well then you are providing additional information that the client context can use if they choose to, or it will act as a default if for some reason the client does not understand or respect the disposition header, or its value.

> By specifying the `Content-Type` many browsers will use this information to determine the file type restriction to apply on the *Save As* dialog, which is especially useful if you are ***NOT*** also specifying the file name.

Some modern web clients (and extensions for them) will inspect the `Content-Type` and choose to deliberately pass the content to application or extension that is registered for that type instead of always saving directly to file, even if the `Content-Disposition` is an attachment. You may have experienced this with PDF viewers.

There are also many older mobile web clients and mini-web browsers embedded within mobile apps that are known to ***not*** support `Content-Disposition` or they deliberately bypass it, instead forcing the content to be rendered directly, so by providing `Content-Type` when you can then you know that you are providing the most compatible output that you reasonably could.

There is a similar discussion on SO, but not directly a duplicate as this question asks why we might include it `Content-Type` knowing that it is not likely to be used.

- [Do I need Content-Type: application/octet-stream for file download?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20509354/1690217)

Comment: Another reason why you should include it is that `Content-Type` is part of the standard, but `Content-Disposition`  is not https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6266#section-1