# Downloading images from Amazon S3 using java spring boot

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS development and I am trying to download objects that are images from my Amazon S3 bucket. I am able to download objects however they are stored like the image below.

[image]

I am using spring boot APIs and my code is here below:

storageService.java

```
package com.fiado.S3.service;



import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Object;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectInputStream;
import com.amazonaws.util.IOUtils;

@Service
public class storageService {
    
    private String bucketName = "fiadoapp";

    @Autowired 
    private AmazonS3 s3Client;
    
     public byte[] downloadFile(String fileName) {
         try {
              byte[] content;
                final S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(bucketName, fileName);
                final S3ObjectInputStream stream = s3Object.getObjectContent();
                content = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
                s3Object.close();
                return content;
            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                ioException.printStackTrace();
            } catch (AmazonServiceException serviceException) {
                serviceException.printStackTrace();
            } catch (AmazonClientException clientException) {
                clientException.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
}
```

storageController.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.fiado.S3.service.storageService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/file")
public class storageController {
    
    @Autowired
    private storageService service;
    
    @GetMapping("/download/{fileName}")
    public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> downloadFile(@PathVariable String fileName) {
        byte[] data = service.downloadFile(fileName);
        
        ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(data);
        
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .contentLength(data.length)
                .header("Content-type","application/octet-stream")
                .header("content-disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                .header("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
                .body(resource);
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Can anyone tell me how I can get my files to be downloaded as images?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need Content-Type: application/octet-stream for file download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508788/do-i-need-content-type-application-octet-stream-for-file-download)

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve my issue. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: HTTP header names are case-insensitive but it would probably still be a good idea to be consistent. You have 3 headers with 3 different forms of capitalization. Also, when you tested with an appropriate Content-Type e.g. image/png or application/pdf, did it make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this code, works perfectly fine downloading images from S3.

only difference is, can you cross check how you are supplying

> fileName

path variable ?

Also, have you tried downloading the file using a standalone program ? just to rule out is

Answer (score 1):

See this AWS tutorial located in the [AWS Code Example Github Repo](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples). It discusses this exact use case and shows you how to download an image located in an Amazon S3 bucket to your web browser using a Spring BOOT app. For example, this image shows downloading an image named **lake.png**.

[image]

This app uses the AWS SDK for Java V2. See:

[Creating a dynamic web application that analyzes photos using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_photo_analyzer_app)

This example uses the Sync Java Client. If you prefer using the Java Async client, see:

[Creating a dynamic web application that asynchronously analyzes photos using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/creating_photo_analyzer_async)

Answer (score 0):

if you need to access the object url you need to make bucket policy public

at permissions tab -> scroll to bucket policy and add this

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
        }
    ]
}
```