# What's the correct MIME to force txt download

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC and I want to force the download of plain text file instead of viewing it.

I was initially using this:

```
return File(download, "application/txt", "Result.txt");
```

And my colleague is telling me I should do this:

```
return File(download, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "Result.txt");
```

We got into some debate over advantages of each, but I still want to know which is the proper one. My computer issues download on both MIMEs on current Firefox & IE versions. IE doesn't show any difference, but Firefox has. File type when downloading `application/txt` is TXT, but when downloading `...Application.Octet` file type is "Secure download manager" (what what?..)

Comment: Perhaps you want `System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain`?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: @shree.pat18 good suggestion but Firefox still shows file type as "Secure download manager", the only one I found for txt yet is `application/txt`

Answer (score 2):

When you have a custom controller that explicitely send the file (i.e. by sending `Content-Disposition`/`Content-Type` HTTP Headers, etc..), then you should give the right MIME type (`text/plain` here).

IMO, the MIME type `application/octet-stream` is used when you don't want to search for the right MIME type (or it won't be recognize anyway), but still want to fire a download.

As shree.pat18 said, `text/plain` can be wrote `System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain` in C#.

Edit: If you google the question, you may have more solutions: [What content type to force download of text response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186867/what-content-type-to-force-download-of-text-response)

Comment: `System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain` issues the download but I sense something not right when the browser is identifying the file type. If I provide `text/plain` then it will not fire up a download but render the text

Comment: Octet is good for anything, but if I know it's txt and I want to fire a download, should I really use it? How come `application/txt` is not good? Am I being stubborn here or do I really miss something that does not have clear specification?