# Download file from nodejs server

Tags: node.js

i have a server nodejs, when download a file from server

```
function download(info) {
    var res = info.res;
    var file = __dirname + '/static/downloads/abc.txt';

    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Content-Length': stat.size
    });

    var readStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
    readStream.pipe(res);
}
```

I don't understand about how can i save file to the disk in client?

Comment: I changed content type but can't fix. response write binary and text data in console

Answer (score 1):

When you offer content type text/plain, but no content-disposition. So your browser will show it in the window...

Use:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"My Text File.txt\"
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186867/what-content-type-to-force-download-of-text-response) for more details

Comment: var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
 client.onreadystatechange = function() {
 };
 client.open("GET", "/download");
 client.send(); i fixed same your solution but it show text in console, no file have to save