# Vuetify v-btn :href download opens XML in browser instead of downloading

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm having hard times making `v-btn` download `XML` file instead of opening it in the browser.

```
 <v-btn :disabled="!exportUrl" block x-large height="100" color="primary" :href="exportUrl" download>
      <v-icon left>
        mdi-download
      </v-icon>
      Stiahnuť
    </v-btn>
```

As far as I know it should download the file, not open the URL. What's wrong with that?

**EDIT**

The URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/4e01d486-ee75-42bc-b695-8b365910ff3e.xml`

**EDIT 2**

The rendered `html` looks like this:

```
<a data-v-51b210ff="" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/10d4a7ad-399d-4003-8841-17eb98769ad9.xml" class="v-btn v-btn--block v-btn--is-elevated v-btn--has-bg theme--light v-size--x-large primary" style="height: 100px;" download=""><span class="v-btn__content"><i data-v-51b210ff="" aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate v-icon--left mdi mdi-download theme--light"></i> Stiahnuť </span></a>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336663/how-to-make-a-browser-display-a-save-as-dialog-so-the-user-can-save-the-conten

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the Content-Type header which is set in the file response.

If it is `application/xml`, the file will be opened as text.
If it is abcent or `application/octet-stream`, then download action will be triggered.

See this question [What content type to force download of text response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186867/what-content-type-to-force-download-of-text-response)

Comment: That's not the case. I don't want to rely on the server. I have the URL and I want to make a button that downloads it instead of rendering it in the browser.

Comment: @Milano, you have asked why is this happening and i answered.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you know if it's possible to make it download the file instead of rendering it? I thought that the "download" parameter would work.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML 5, there is a `download` attribute on the `a` tag. You just need to place the downloaded file's name in the attribute, and it should automatically download the file for you.